# How can I read confidence data (password) in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to improve this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cplkacpelaknlngmmhfkhoanmlfgjokf)
to add the following functionality.

When the user click or focus on a password box ( `<input type="password" />`), a dialog appears. The user can type in his password. After that the extension automatically calculate encrypted password, and fill into the password box.

Firstly, I implement it by modifying DOM, add a jQuery UI dialog. But I realize that this may have some security risk. The web page can iterate through the whole page, find my password box and get its value. Is this right? If is, how can I read password safely?

I also try to find a way to programmatically "click" the page action or browser action to show a password box. But seems forbidden by Chrome. No such interface.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can learn from [this example](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/07/stealing-login-details-with-google.html). Perhaps you're not (or maybe you are) stealing passwords, but this shows how you can read the content of `<input type="password" />` fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt) from a content script. This will make it more secure in that the page won't have access to the result. This is also not secure however since any website can detect if the extension is installed and create their own prompt.

Another option is to use [desktop notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html). This would be a little more secure since only installed extensions and websites that get permission to show notifications could show a prompt. It also allows for html notifications that could use a password field.

A third option would be to use the experimental [infobar API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.infobars.html). Unfortunately you won't be able to publish an experimental API to the Chrome Web Store.